# MFCC feature vector from wav file

Tags: audio, mfcc, classification, reference-implementation

I am trying to implement a spoken language identifier from audio files, using Neural Network. I need to generate one feature vector for each audio file.

From what I have read the best features (for my purpose) to extract from the a .wav audio file are the MFCC.

Does anyone know of a Python code that does such a thing?

Comment: Your question is too broad. We can't really just explain how to pick an appropriate feature extractor without writing a couple thousand lines of code or writing a textbook on speech recognition. That's exactly what I'd recommend here: read a textbook on classical speech recognition. And instead of the classical classificators, you plug in DNNs.

Comment: use python_speech_features; a library to extract features from sounds; look for it on github

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these two python libraries that provide a number of audio features easily from WAV files, including MFCC.

- Librosa: [MFCC docs](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.mfcc.html), [github](https://github.com/librosa/librosa)
- Madmom: [MFCC docs](http://madmom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/audio/cepstrogram.html?highlight=mfcc), [github](https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom)

Good luck!